# Can you please check my proof of this limit of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I proved the following:

> If $f$ is differentiable on an interval containing $0$ and if $\lim_{x
> > \to 0} f'(x) = L$ then $f'(0) = L$.

Please can you tell me if my proof is correct:

By contradiction assume $f'(0) \neq L$. Without loss of generality assume $f'(0) > L$. Also without loss of generality assume $L>0$. Since $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = L$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$ 0 < |x|<\delta \implies |f'(x) -L|<{L\over 2}$$

which implies that for $ 0 < |x|<\delta$ it holds that $0 \le f'(x)<{L\over 2}$. Fix $x_0>0$ with $f'(x_0)< {L \over 2}$. Then 
$$f'(0) > L > {L\over 2}>f'(x_0) $$

but there is no $c \in (0,x_0)$ with $f'(c) = L$ which is a contradiction to Darboux's theorem. Hence it must holds that $f'(0) = L$.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your comment. But $f$ is differentiable on an interval containing zero hence $f$ is differentiable at zero hence $f' (0)$ exists. Why can I not argue like this?

Comment: yes you are right. I was thinking about the case where $0$ is at the boundary of the interval. Stupid me, sorry.

Comment: @Thomas No problem at all. But assuming that it exists, is my proof correct? Feel free to post an answer so I can reward your effort adequately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, I do have my doubts how you arrive at the conclusion $f^\prime(x) < \frac{L}{2}$. I get $f^\prime(x)< \frac{3L}{2}$ or $f^\prime(x) >\frac{1}{2}$ Also, assuming you can show that, you should at least explain why you may assume that $L\neq 0$, since you make explicit use of that fact (this is of course easy, you can, e.g. just add $ax$ to $f$)

To be honest, I also think the approach is too complicated. I hope you don't mind if I propose an easier approach: by the mean value theorem, for each $x$ near $0$ there is $c\in (0,x)$ (or $\in (x, 0)$, depending on the sign of $x$), such that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = f^\prime(c)$$
Now if you let $x\rightarrow 0$ you get the claim immediately from the definition of differentiability and the assumption about the convergence of $f^\prime$ (since, of course, the corresponding $c\rightarrow 0$, as well).

This path of thought actually incited me to write my first comment, now deleted (which said you need to show first that $f^\prime(0)$ exists). With this reasoning you don't need to know that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, you get it for free.

Comment: You are right, it's $3 L / 2$. But the argument also works with $3L/2$. And it is a good point that I should state why $L \neq 0$. Is the proof otherwise correct? This question came up after reading parts of a book and the mean value theorem is only discussed later so I am trying to prove it without MVT.

Comment: out of curiosity: how do you know the Darboux theorem without using MVT? To the question: how does the argument work with $3L/2$? You only know $f^\prime(0) >L$

Comment: You are right it doesn't work. But instead of $|f'(x) -L|<{L\over 2}$ I could use $|f'(x) -L|< L + {|L - f'(0)|\over 2}$ and then it should work. The Darboux theorem is easy to prove (without MVT) and it is used to prove MVT. But not the other way around?

Comment: No, I get it. My arguemnt is flawed.

Comment: @Thomas  I came here via http://math.stackexchange.com/q/766015/337283, where you said that for the differentiability argument you can see this post. However, there is something I doubt about this argument solving the second question of the link above, because for applying the mean value theorem you need to know $f$ is differentiable at $0$, or in the case of the link, at $a$.

Comment: @M.Van This is incorrect, the assumption for the mean value theorem is continuity on $[a,b]$ and differentiability on $(a,b)$.

Comment: Ah, I did not know this, the counterexample I had in mind was indeed not continuous in $a$. My bad!

Comment: I'm sorry for commenting on a 6 year old question, I know this will probably take time reading again (both the question and the answer perhaps), but doesn't your method of proof assume that $f'$ is continuous at 0? I've been thinking about this proof for the past days and when you do the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(c(x))$ you are using the theorem which says that $\lim f(g(x)) = f(\lim g(x))$ when $f$ is continuous at $\lim g(x)$. This way, you are using the conclusion as part of the proof.

Comment: @StefanOctavian No, I don't. The _question_ assumes that the limit of the derivative exists when $x\rightarrow 0$. What can then be shown by the above reasoning is that the derivative exists at $x= 0$ (this is also assumed in the question, but it follows from the assumptions) and that it is actually continuous in that point.The proof just uses the definition of the derivative at $x=0$, as the limit of the difference quotients, and the mean value theorem (which is valid without any assumption on the behavior at $x=0$).

Comment: I'm talking about the interchange of limit and function argument on the right hand side. "Now if you let $x \to 0$", that is the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(c)$ and you are assuming that it is equal to $f'(\lim_{x\to 0} c) = f'(0)$, but this follows strictly from continuity of $f'$ at 0 which is not yet proved.

Comment: @StefanOctavian There is no interchange of limit, I don't know where you perceive this. The starting point is the difference quotient for $f$, for arbitrary $x$. If $x\rightarrow 0$, then $c\rightarrow 0$ and $f^\prime(c)$ converges, _by assumption_ to some real number $r$. But $f^\prime (c) =\frac{f(x) - f(0) }{x}$, so if $f^\prime (c)$ converges then so does this difference quotient, to the very same number. But that is, again, _by definition_ $=f^\prime(0)$.

Comment: Oh, I think I see it now. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. The implication $\left(f'(x) \to \ell, x \to 0\right) \rightarrow \left(f'(c) \to \ell, c \to 0, x \to 0\right)$ was what I was missing and the way this proof was put in my textbook had me all confused. Please let me know if you want me to delete my comments.