# Proof without mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

Is it possible to prove the following without using the mean value theorem:

> If $f$ is differentiable on an interval containing $0$ and if $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = L$ then $f'(0) = L$.

I have tried ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697780/can-you-please-check-my-proof-of-this-limit-of-derivative)) but I'm running out of ideas and I'm wondering if it's possible at all.

Comment: L'Hôpital's will work. Or Darboux's Theorem. But using either of these in place of MVT seems silly to me.

Comment: @DavidMitra Using Darboux's theorem is what I tried in the question I link to in the question but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The MVT is really the simplest tool you can use. Here an "alternative" proof.

By considering $f(x)-f(0)-xL$ we reduce to the case where $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

Claim: there is a sequence of points $x_n\to0$ s.t. $f'(x_n)\to 0$. Since $f'(x)$ has a limit when $x\to 0$ the claim concludes.

Proof of the claim. Suppose the contrary. 
Therefore in a neighborhood of $0$ we have no local maxima or minima, because there the derivative is zero.

REMARK: This is equivalent to reproving the MVT!!!

Thus $f$ is monotone near zero, say increasing. Again by contradicting the claim, we get  $f'(x)>\epsilon$ near zero. Thus $f(x)>\epsilon x$ near zero (this is again another hidden instance of the MVT). This makes impossible to have $f'(0)=0$.

But as David Mitra said, the MVT is a simple and useful result, why don't use it directly?

Comment: It should be noted that the derivative of a everywhere differentiable function has the property that if $f'(a)=x$ and $f'(b)=y$ then for any $z\in(x,y)$ there is $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=y$. This is a remarkable property of the derivative as $f'$ need not to be continue.

Comment: You mean $f'(c)=z$, I think.

Comment: yes, sure, sorry