# Local implicit function theorem and Global implicit function theorem

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

Suppose that $f=f(x,y)$ is $C^1$ in $x$ and $y$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x_0,y_0)=0$. Moreover, $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}>0$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Could we conclude that $y$ can be solved implicitly from $f(x,y)=0$ in terms of $x$ as $y=y(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$? If the answer is no and an additional assumption is imposed, i.e. we can obtain $y'(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ by implicitly differentiating $f(x,y(x))=0$ with respect to $x$, then these assumptions are enough to get the same conclusion?

Comment: maybe this is of interest for you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678417/implicit-function-not-obvious-version/678456#678456

Comment: Yes, that link helps much, thanks! I'm thinking what you said about using the mean value theorem to show that $\varphi$ can be extended in $C^1$ to the boundary of any finite interval, hence to $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Would you please give some hints?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to know beyond what is shown in [this question and it's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678417/implicit-function-not-obvious-version/678456#678456), but that question shows already where you have to expect the result to break down. As an example, consider

$$F(x,y) = - e^{-y} +x$$
Clearly, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = e^{-y}>0$ everywhere, but it is easy to see that  $F$ is strictly negative for $x\le0$ on the one hand side but admits a (obviously unique) solution of $F(x,y) = 0$ for each $x>0$. This shows that if the bounds on the derivates no longer hold, the solution may go off to infinity (Which is exactly what happens in this example).

Answer (score -1):

For Global Implicit Function Theorem you need "somewhat" stronger assumption, namely,  $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\geq d>0,$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,$ $d$ is constant. See, for example, Lemma 1 and its proof in:

*Ge, S.S.; Wang, C.*, [**Adaptive NN control of uncertain nonlinear pure-feedback systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0005-1098(01)00254-0), Automatica 38, No.4, 671-682 (2002). [ZBL0998.93025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0998.93025).