Given continuous $F(s,t)$ and $C(t)$, find $s(x)$ and $t(y)$ such that $F(s(x),t(y)) = C(x+y)$
I'm asking this question because I have a particular application on my hands, and it seems to need some mathematical machinery, but I haven't been able to figure out what to search for.
Given
Suppose we have a continuous function $F(s,t):\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R $. For the sake of example, suppose $F(s,t) = st$
Suppose we are also given another continuous function $C(t):\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. For the sake of example, suppose $C(t) = t$
Find
Find two continuous functions $s(x):\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $t(y):\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that:
$$ F(s(x),t(y)) = C(x+y) $$
The idea here is that we can apply some transformation to the inputs of $F$ such that the resulting function of the $x$ and $y$ parameters has this nice homomorphism-type property.
The question
Even for the simple example given above, I haven't been able to find a solution. (If we had picked a different example, such as $F(x,y) = x+y$ and $C(t)=t$, then you could just pick $s(x) = x$ and $t(y) = y$)
I don't even know if this sort of problem is solvable in the first place. Maybe $F$ needs to be commutative? Or maybe there are strict requirements on $C$? This whole problem seems so close to the definition of a homomorphism, but I just can't seem to get my head around it. Does anyone know what terms I should be looking up?

Is it essential that your functions are only continuous? If you make them continuously differentiable, you could use the implicite function theorem to get a local solution. There are versions without differentiability, but I cannot remember which topological properties one needs to assume instead.

Your example doesn't seem to have a solution. E.g. $s(0)t(1)=s(1)t(0)=1$, so $s(0),t(0) \neq 0$, but $s(0)t(0)=0$.

This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678417/implicit-function-not-obvious-version/678456#678456 might be a good starting point.

Yeah yeah yeah yeah! I think this is it! Okay, it looks like I can cast this into an implicit function theorem form. Define $G(s,t) = F(s,t) - C(s+t)$. Then, according to the implicit function theorem, supposing there exists some $s_0, t_0$ such that $G(s_0, t_0) = 0$ and $D_tG(s0,t0) \neq 0$ then there exists a function $y(s)$ such that $G(s, y(s)) = 0$ in the "neighbourhood" of $s_0,t_0$. I think I can take it from here with a numerical solution, I'll need to try it out. Thank you!!!!!!
